# How can I find the pid of Android's SurfaceFlinger service?

Tags: android, adb, surfaceflinger

I would like to investigate the process ID of said service on Android. I have an Android 9 and access via adb. Can anyone help me? Can I find out the PID using the command `top` or `pidof`? Or is there another way to get the PID of the SurfaceFlinger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adb shell ps | grep surfaceflinger`

Comment: BTW, if you are already in the shell via `adb shell` then you have to type `ps -A | grep surfaceflinger` (at least for me)